# How to Merge each 28 lines into 1 line on notepad++ from 1 million lines?

Tags: notepad++

Is there any way of doing this, I know there are regex codes but I seem to can not find the right one...

It stars from

```
<tr>
<td>28 lines in between</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do not use notepad++ for large files it will stuck and get unresponsive performing bunch operations. There are alternative editors intended to work with such large files I don't want to advertise them here so use google to look for "large file editors"

Comment: I have slickedit installed, but can not find any tutorial for that either...

Comment: Consider contacting NASA?! - (Also, have you tried anything code-wise so far?)

Comment: @I Love CSS actually its a 10 million line text file, but to keep trolls away I kept it hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `(<td>.*)\R(.*)`
- **Replace With:** `\1 \2`
- check **regular expression**
- be sure to have '. matches newline` **not** checken
- click **Replace All**
- wait about a minute (depends on your CPU), now the first two lines are merged in every `<td>`
- click **Replace All** 26 more times.